# What -next means in semantic versioning

Tags: versioning, semantic-versioning

What is the meaning of pre-release version `x.x.x-next` in semantic versioning, for example `6.0.0-next.0`, `6.0.0-next.1`, `6.0.0-next.2`? I saw this terminology at least in [angular](https://github.com/angular/angular/releases) and [npm](https://github.com/npm/cli/releases) projects. Is this replacement of legacy `alpha`, `beta`, `rc` nomenclature? I haven't seen any explonation why these projects are using that terminology.

Answer (score 3):

Per the spec in https://semver.org (2.0.0), item 9, there's nothing official about `alpha`, `beta`, or `rc` nomenclature.  These just happen to appear in several examples throughout the spec.  `next` is an equally legitimate pre-release identifier per the published BNF grammar.